# Unity get Animation of Animator by name

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

Hey guys I have a Question:
I want to get a specific animation of the animator by script. I know the name of the animation and I want to get this animation of the animator by name how do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should solve your problem.

```
public AnimationClip FindAnimation (Animator animator, string name) 
{
   foreach (AnimationClip clip in animator.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips)
   {
      if (clip.name == name)
      {
         return clip;
      }
   }

   return null;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Happy to be helpful. Happy Easter.